# Nuxt slow compiling & building

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a page file which has more than 900 lines of HTML code. It also includes CSS and JS code. It takes a lot of time to build and compile. I checked on both Linux and Windows environments. Help me on this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem with Nuxt 2.4.

What is really frustrating is that I am only making changes in my Express (index.js) file and when saving both the client and server rebuild.